# How to delete all data on server beyond recover?

Tags: linux, openvz

I have migrated my collocation servers to Amazon EC2, I would like to delete all the data beyond recovery for security reasons. Any ideas? What is the best way to go about this? I am running OpenVZ on the old servers and have 4 containers. I want the content of these containers to be deleted forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run [shred](http://linux.die.net/man/1/shred) on the disk images from the *host* if you just want the containers deleted

If you want a one step process, and to clear out the whole drive, you can just run [dban](http://www.dban.org/) on each server